# Log In user with the membership provider

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Hi I am trying to create an e-commerce website with asp.net MVC3.I am at the part where I have to login the User into my application.I can validate it's credentials but I can not seem to able to log him in.Here is what I have so far:

```
if(Membership.ValidateUser(model.Username , model.Password))
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index" , returnUrl);
    }
}
```

I know I still have to add something here to log the user into my application but I do not know what.Can anyone please tell me what do I have to do next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Forms authentication, you need to set the Authentication cookie:

```
    if(Membership.ValidateUser(model.Username , model.Password))
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie( model.UserName, model.RememberMe );
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
            {//...
```

Also, you should read this article on [preventing open redirection attacks](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/security/preventing-open-redirection-attacks).